# How to properly search xml document using LINQ C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a hard time time figuring out how to properly search an xml document. I have been reading the other forms like crazy today but just can't seem to understand it.  Was hopeing someone could give me a little more detailed information on how to do this the correct way and why using LINQ.  Here is the XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<body>
  <Customers>
    <Client>
      <Firstname Value="someguy" />
      <LastName Value="test" />
      <PhoneNumber Value="541555555" />
      <Address Value="55 nowhere" />
      <City Value="sometown" />
      <State Value="somestate" />
    </Client>
  </Customers>
</body>
```

What I am tyring to accomplish is to return all of the values of each element that matches by a name of a customer. Here is my code.

```
       IEnumerable<XElement> test = doc.Root.Descendants()
            .Where(nodeName => nodeName.Name == "Client"
            && nodeName.Descendants().Any(x => x.Name == "Firstname"
            && x.Value == "someguy"));

        foreach (XElement m in test)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(m.ToString());
        }
```

Would really appreciate the help.  Please also if possible explain what the idea of using LINQ is like the format if you will. Not really sure how to explain what I am asking but for the most part just more understanding of the way it works or format etc...

**EDIT**

I have tried the solution given and still nothing is seeming to work.  Please show me what I am doing wrong here.

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string seach = txtSearch.Text;

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\users\tim\desktop\test.xml");

        var result = doc.Elements("Customers")
            .Elements("Client")
            .Where(x => x.Elements("Firstname")
                         .Where(c => c.Attribute("Value").Value == "someguy")
                         .Any())
            .ToList();

        foreach (var m in result)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(m.ToString());
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Okay so I have gotten it to work now and output the data that I was looking for. Can someone please tell me if there is a more efficent way of doing what I have posted below this edit.

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string seach = txtSearch.Text;

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\users\tim\desktop\test.xml");

        var result = (from clientNode in doc.Root.Descendants("Client")
                      from name in clientNode.Descendants("Firstname")
                      where name.Attribute("Value").Value == "someguy"
                      select new
                      {
                          Fname = clientNode.Element("Firstname").Attribute("Value").Value,
                          Lname = clientNode.Element("LastName").Attribute("Value").Value,
                          Phone = clientNode.Element("PhoneNumber").Attribute("Value").Value,
                          Address = clientNode.Element("Address").Attribute("Value").Value,
                          City = clientNode.Element("City").Attribute("Value").Value,
                          State = clientNode.Element("State").Attribute("Value").Value
                      });

        foreach (var m in result)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(m.Fname + "\n" +
                            m.Lname + "\n" +
                            m.Phone + "\n" +
                            m.Address + "\n" +
                            m.City + "\n" +
                            m.State);
        }
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what do you want. Do you want to get `Client` node if it has satisfying `Firstname.Value="someguy"` condition?

Comment: basically what I am trying to do is get all of the values of each element inside element that matches my condition for example.  I am searching for "someguy" I need all the info his # his address etc...

Comment: @Timg `XElement doc = XElement.Parse(xml);`

Comment: so I have to put the xml into the code itself? vs accessing it from the individual file?

Comment: @Timg Did you read note part of my answer?

Comment: @Timg for example `XElement doc = XElement.Load(@"d:\file.xml");`

Comment: @Timg and pay attention, use `XElement`

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thank you that was the issue I wasn't using the Xelement.load()  Thanks again!!!

Comment: @Timg you are welcome:)

Comment: so only other question.. Is there any more efficent way to get the data printed out for example like a foreach loop etc.. as the list really only has a count of 1?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91002/discussion-between-timg-and-reza-aghaei).

Comment: @Timg Yes, there is, if result is a single item, you can use result.Elements() and loop through items and print what you need, Also you can use linq techniques to do this:)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`XElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) and search using a LINQ query like these:

```
XElement doc = XElement.Parse(xml);
var result = doc.Elements("Customers")
                .Elements("Client")
                .Where(x => x.Elements("Firstname")
                             .Where(c => c.Attribute("Value").Value == "someguy")
                             .Any())
                .ToList();
```

So with input:

```
var xml =
@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<body>
    <Customers>
    <Client>
        <Firstname Value=""someguy"" />
        <LastName Value=""some last name"" />
        <PhoneNumber Value=""123456"" />
        <Address Value=""some where"" />
        <City Value=""some town"" />
        <State Value=""some state"" />
    </Client>
    <Client>
        <Firstname Value=""someotherguy"" />
        <LastName Value=""some other last name"" />
        <PhoneNumber Value=""123456"" />
        <Address Value=""some other where"" />
        <City Value=""some other town"" />
        <State Value=""some other state"" />
    </Client>
    </Customers>
</body>";

XElement doc = XElement.Parse(xml);
var result = doc.Elements("Customers")
                .Elements("Client")
                .Where(x => x.Elements("Firstname")
                             .Where(c => c.Attribute("Value").Value == "someguy")
                             .Any())
                .ToList();
```

The result will be:

```
<Client>
    <Firstname Value=""someguy"" />
    <LastName Value=""some last name"" />
    <PhoneNumber Value=""123456"" />
    <Address Value=""some where"" />
    <City Value=""some town"" />
    <State Value=""some state"" />
</Client>
```

And you can show values for example:

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Firstname: {0}\nLastName: {1}\nPhoneNumber: {2}\nAddress: {3}\nCity: {4}\nState: {5}",
                result[0].Element("Firstname").Attribute("Value").Value,
                result[0].Element("LastName").Attribute("Value").Value,
                result[0].Element("PhoneNumber").Attribute("Value").Value,
                result[0].Element("Address").Attribute("Value").Value,
                result[0].Element("City").Attribute("Value").Value,
                result[0].Element("State").Attribute("Value").Value));
```

**Note:**

- If you know the result should contain 0 or 1 elements, you can use `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `ToList()`;
- Element names are case sensitive so pay attention to **Firstname** for example.
- You can use `XElement.Load()` to load from file for example `XElement doc = XElement.Load(@"d:\file.xml");`
- The query will be more fault tolerant if you select elements this way `.Where(c => c.Name.ToString().ToLower() == "Customers".ToLower())`
- The query will be more fault-tolerant if you select attributes this way `.Where(c => c.Attributes("Value").Where(a=>a.Value == "someguy").Any())`

Comment: Good solution, but it should be noted that it does no checking if elements actually exist and will throw an exception if, for example, the `Customers` element is not present. Also, instead of `.Elements("Customers").First()`, you can use `.Element("Customers")`.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to @Reza Aghaei's solution, `XPath` is also a solution

```
var xml =
@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<body>
    <Customers>
    <Client>
        <Firstname Value=""someguy"" />
        <LastName Value=""some last name"" />
        <PhoneNumber Value=""123456"" />
        <Address Value=""some where"" />
        <City Value=""some town"" />
        <State Value=""some state"" />
    </Client>
    <Client>
        <Firstname Value=""someotherguy"" />
        <LastName Value=""some other last name"" />
        <PhoneNumber Value=""123456"" />
        <Address Value=""some other where"" />
        <City Value=""some other town"" />
        <State Value=""some other state"" />
    </Client>
    <Client>
        <Firstname Value=""someguy"" />
        <LastName Value=""some other last name"" />
        <PhoneNumber Value=""12345634543"" />
        <Address Value=""some other where"" />
        <City Value=""some other town"" />
        <State Value=""some other state"" />
    </Client>
    </Customers>
</body>";
XElement doc = XElement.Parse(xml);

foreach(var client in doc
 .XPathSelectElements("./Customers/Client/Firstname[@Value='someguy']")
 .Select(x => x.Parent))
    Console.WriteLine (client);
```

If you prefer a **Linq To Xml** solution :

```
var results = (from c in doc.Descendants("Client")
            from f in c.Descendants("Firstname")
             where (string)f.Attribute("Value") == "someguy"
             select c).ToList();
foreach(var r in results)
    Console.WriteLine (r);
```

[How to: Write Linq to Xml Queries with Complex Filtering](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387032.aspx)

Comment: I will edit my main post but for some reason I have tried using the solutions you are giving me and still no dice.. I have no idea what I am doing wrong here please help me explain.