# how to read nested node from XML file

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

This is an example of what my XML file typically looks like. It can contain any amount of assignments and any amount of modules and can contain 3 levels. (I haven't included the other 2 levels for now).

```
<course name="engineering">
    <level4>
        <module name="electric" credit="22">
            <assignment name="wer" marks="22" weight="50">
            </assignment>
            <assignment name="asd" marks="50" weight="50">
            </assignment>
        </module>
    </level4>
</course>
```

This is what I have so far

```
while (tr.Read())
{
    tr.MoveToElement();
    if (tr.Name == "Course") {
        courseXML.Name = tr.GetAttribute("name");
    }
    if (tr.Name == "Level4") {

    }
}
```

I am reading the XML file but I stumbled upon a problem. How do I get to module elements and the assignment elements and how would I be able to iterate through them because my XML file can contain any amount of modules and assignment.

Comment: Take a look at [`XDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`XElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement(v=vs.110).aspx) classes. You can simply use linq to find nodes. For example you may find this post helpful: [How to properly search xml document using LINQ C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32853397/how-to-properly-search-xml-document-using-linq-c-sharp).

Answer (score 1):

If the xml is not to big you can do it like this:

```
    public static List<XmlObject> FindTagsWithChildTags(string xml, string tag,string childTag,string attribute)
    {
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(xml);
        if (xdoc.Descendants(tag).Any())
        {
            var lv1s = (from lv1 in xdoc.Descendants(tag)
                        select new XmlObject
                        {
                            Element = "",
                            Value = lv1.Attribute(attribute).Value.ToLower(),
                            Field = attribute ,
                            XmlObjects = (from lv2 in lv1.Descendants(childTag)
                                         select new XmlObject
                                         {
                                             Element="",
                                             Field=lv1.FirstAttribute.Name.LocalName,
                                             Value = lv1.FirstAttribute.Value.ToLower()
                                         }).ToList()
                        }).ToList();

            return lv1s;
        }
        return new List<XmlObject>();
    }
```

if you have a very big xml you can read it like this

```
    List<Info> infos = new List<Info>();
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
   // settings.Schemas.Add("urn:empl-hire", "hireDate.xsd");
    using (System.Xml.XmlReader reader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(xmlPath, settings))
    {            
        reader.MoveToContent();
      while(reader.ReadToFollowing("ServiceInformation"))
      {
          string serviceId = reader.GetAttribute("serviceId");
          string serviceUrl = "";
          if (reader.ReadToDescendant("ServiceURL"))
          {
              serviceUrl = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
          }
          Info info = new Info();
          info.ID = serviceId;
          info.Value1 = serviceUrl;
          infos.Add(info);
      }

    }
    return infos;
```

These are examples i used i hope they help you!