# search particular value in xml

Tags: c#, xml

I have this particular xml file element. I want to Fetch the param-value if the param-name is "Religion Name". How to search in using LINQ using C#?

1. Read and load the xml file file.
2. Search the param-name.
3. Get the param-value.

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>Religion Name</param-name>
        <param-value>Roman Catholic</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>Name</param-name>
        <param-value>James Smith</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32853397/how-to-properly-search-xml-document-using-linq-c-sharp

Comment: this is the sample xml file. reading from web.xml file https://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer/cb1d8a91

Answer (score 0):

```
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml("<root>\r\n  <context-param>\r\n    <param-name>Religion Name</param-name>\r\n    <param-value>Roman Catholic</param-value>\r\n  </context-param>\r\n  <context-param>\r\n    <param-name>Name</param-name>\r\n    <param-value>James Smith</param-value>\r\n  </context-param>\r\n</root>");

        var nameList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("param-name");
        var valueList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("param-value");
        for (int i = 0; i < nameList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (nameList[i].InnerXml.Equals("Religion Name"))
            {
                //get your value
                var value= valueList[i].InnerXml;
            }

        }
```

Comment: this is the sample xml file. reading from web.xml file https://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer/cb1d8a91

Comment: Please modify your post then because you are not asking for the web.xml file

Answer (score 0):

I like using a dictionary for these type programs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication132
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<string, string> dict = doc.Descendants("context-param")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Element("param-name"), y => (string)y.Element("param-value"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

            string religion = dict["Religion Name"];

        }
    }


}
```